# How to add button or change long url to other name from document.getElementById .setAttribute href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to ask: I created a select option with some values, example like this :

```js
function updateinput(e) {
 
var selectedOption = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex];
   var url = selectedOption.getAttribute('data-url');
document.getElementById('data1').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data1');
document.getElementById('data2').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data2');
document.getElementById('data3').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data3');
document.getElementById('data4').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data4');
document.getElementById('data5').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data5');
document.getElementById('data-url').setAttribute('href', url);
  document.getElementById('data-url').innerHTML=url;
}
```

```html
<select onChange="updateinput(event)">
<option data1='1.000.000' data2='0,-' data3='0,-' data4='0,-' data5='1.000.000' data-url='http://google.com'>30 Day</option>
<option data1='1.500.000' data2='500.000,-' data3='0,-' data4='0,-' data5='2.000.000' data-url='http://yahoo.com'>60 Day</option>
</select>

<input id="data1" name="data1" readonly type="text">
<input id="data2" name="data2" readonly type="text">
<input id="data3" name="data3" readonly type="text">
<input id="data4" name="data4" readonly type="text">
<input id="data5" name="data5" readonly type="text">
<a id="data-url" name="data-url">Anchor</a>
```

i want change the url http://google.com or http://yahoo.com to button

i try like this :

`<a id="data-url" name="data-url" type="button">Anchor</a>` not work (button not show)

`<button><a id="data-url" name="data-url">Anchor</a></button>` (button show, but the link is not in the button)

if can't change into button, change the url http://google.com or http://yahoo.com like this : **Google** **Yahoo** (other text but still clickable)

1. [**Google**](http://google.com)
2. [**Yahoo**](http://yahoo.com)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just use the `<a>`-element and style it with css or in between the `<style>`-tags to look like a button.

Comment: thanks sir for reply, i try to add <a> not work sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can style the `<a>`-Link-element with CSS to look like a Button. I guess that'll fit your needs.

I gave the `<option>`-elements another `data-attribute` named `data-name`. Then I called them "*Google*" and "*Yahoo*" and this name gets printed onto the `textContent` while the actual link goes into the `href`-attribute from the link.

For the future:
Save your DOM-Elements in variables, so you can use them more easily. That's where `link.href` comes from.

```js
function updateinput(e) {
var selectedOption = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex];
var url = selectedOption.getAttribute('data-url');
var name = selectedOption.getAttribute("data-name");
const link = document.getElementById('data-url');
const data1 = document.getElementById('data1');
const data2 = document.getElementById('data2')
const data3 = document.getElementById('data3')
const data4 = document.getElementById('data4')
const data5 = document.getElementById('data5')

data1.value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data1');
data2.value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data2');
data3.value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data3');
data4.value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data4');
data5.value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data5');

link.href = url;
link.textContent = name;
link.classList.remove("hidden");
}
```

```css
#data-url{
  font: bold 11px Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<select onChange="updateinput(event)">
<option selected="selected" hidden="hidden"></option>
<option data1='1.000.000' data2='0,-' data3='0,-' data4='0,-' data5='1.000.000' data-url='http://google.com' data-name="Google">30 Day</option>
<option data1='1.500.000' data2='500.000,-' data3='0,-' data4='0,-' data5='2.000.000' data-url='http://yahoo.com' data-name="Yahoo">60 Day</option>
</select>

<input id="data1" name="data1" readonly type="text">
<input id="data2" name="data2" readonly type="text">
<input id="data3" name="data3" readonly type="text">
<input id="data4" name="data4" readonly type="text">
<input id="data5" name="data5" readonly type="text">
<a id="data-url" class="hidden" name="data-url">Anchor</a>
```

***EDIT:***

- Added class `hidden` to the Anchor to make it invisible at start.
- Added empty `<option>` as default select, and hidden so it won't
  appear in the dropdown.
- Added `link.classList.remove` as soon as an option is selected to
  show `Anchor`.
- Refactored JS for readability.

Comment: thanks sir for reply, sorry sir, how to change **http://yahoo.com** to Yahoo but still clickable in button?

Comment: sorry sir can ask again, how to hidden button "Anchor" if no select

Comment: @umild I updated the snippet to your needs, was kinda busy sry for the delay in answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<a style="border:1px solid green; padding: 5px 8px; background-color: grey; color: white;" id="data-url" name="data-url" type="button">Anchor</a>
```

in this case your link will be like a button...

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for. Added a button class to `<a>` and styled in css as a button.
For more the following  link will help you to add css to your button class as  you want. Have a look on [this link](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ButtonMaker/#)

```js
function updateinput(e) {

  var selectedOption = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex];
  var url = selectedOption.getAttribute('data-url');
  document.getElementById('data1').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data1');
  document.getElementById('data2').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data2');
  document.getElementById('data3').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data3');
  document.getElementById('data4').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data4');
  document.getElementById('data5').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data5');
  document.getElementById('data-url').setAttribute('href', url);
  document.getElementById('data-url').innerHTML = url;
}
```

```css
.button{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background-image: none;
    background-color:#ddd;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<select onChange="updateinput(event)">
  <option data1='1.000.000' data2='0,-' data3='0,-' data4='0,-' data5='1.000.000' data-url='http://google.com'>30 Day</option>
  <option data1='1.500.000' data2='500.000,-' data3='0,-' data4='0,-' data5='2.000.000' data-url='http://yahoo.com'>60 Day</option>
</select>

<input id="data1" name="data1" readonly type="text">
<input id="data2" name="data2" readonly type="text">
<input id="data3" name="data3" readonly type="text">
<input id="data4" name="data4" readonly type="text">
<input id="data5" name="data5" readonly type="text">
<a id="data-url" class="button" name="data-url">Anchor</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make an input or a buttton element instead of your a-tag.

```
... <input id="data-url" type="button" onclick="data-url-location-href';" value="data-url" /> ....
```

You only need to update your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

> i want change the url http://google.com or http://yahoo.com to button

Just wrap `<button>` with `<a>`

> how to change yahoo.com to Yahoo but still clickable in button?

Since you have already used `data-*` attribute, you may put that in use here. Or, just use the `value` attribute of button instead.

```css
button:after {
  content: attr(data-text);
}
```

```html
<a href="http://yahoo.com" target="_blank"><button data-text="Yahoo"></button></a>
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank"><button data-text="Google"></button></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess you can work on this if you mention the target on `<a>` tag

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank" class="btn btn-default">Go to Google</a>
```

Try this Code:

```js
function updateinput(e) {
 
var selectedOption = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex];
   var url = selectedOption.getAttribute('data-url');
document.getElementById('data1').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data1');
document.getElementById('data2').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data2');
document.getElementById('data3').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data3');
document.getElementById('data4').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data4');
document.getElementById('data5').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data5');
  var aTag = document.getElementById("data-url");
aTag.setAttribute('href',url);
if(url=='http://google.com')
  aTag.innerHTML = "Google";
else
  aTag.innerHTML = "Yahoo";

}
```

```html
<select onChange="updateinput(event)">
<option data1='1.000.000' data2='0,-' data3='0,-' data4='0,-' data5='1.000.000' data-url='http://google.com'>30 Day</option>
<option data1='1.500.000' data2='500.000,-' data3='0,-' data4='0,-' data5='2.000.000' data-url='http://yahoo.com'>60 Day</option>
</select>

<input id="data1" name="data1" readonly type="text">
<input id="data2" name="data2" readonly type="text">
<input id="data3" name="data3" readonly type="text">
<input id="data4" name="data4" readonly type="text">
<input id="data5" name="data5" readonly type="text">
  <a id="data-url" target="_blank" name="data-url">Anchor</a>
```